# How to run a linear model by group in Python?

Tags: python, regression

I’m beginning with Python that I need to use to run a linear model for the dataset below :
Location    Y   X1  X2
1           32  1   1
1           44  1   2
1           58  1   3
1           76  2   1
1           73  2   2
1           37  2   3
1           52  3   1
1           78  3   2
1           60  3   3
2           93  1   1
2           78  1   2
2           25  1   3
2           97  2   1
2           85  2   2
2           60  2   3
2           70  3   1
2           62  3   2
2          95   3   3

My target is to run a linear model as follows :
Y ~ X1 + X2
And for that the following code gave me exactly what I need :
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import scipy.stats as stats

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
reg = ols('Y ~ C(X1) + C(X2)', data=df).fit() 
df['fitted_values'] = reg.fittedvalues
result = reg.outlier_test()
df['student_resid'] = result.student_resid
```

What I’m not able to do is to run this code by ‘Location’, and get my columns 'fitted_values' and 'student_resid' accordingly.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance.
Regards,